# Extracting ip address and interface name from ifconfig

Tags: shell, freebsd, ifconfig

I have task extract ip addresses and interface list from ifconfig.

OS FreeBSD

ifconfig output:

```
em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=9b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM>
        ether 00:50:56:a5:42:13
        inet 192.168.1.5 netmask 0xfffffff0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fea1:4213%em0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
em1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=9b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM>
        ether 00:50:56:a1:62:19
        inet 172.16.16.16 netmask 0xfffffffc broadcast 172.16.16.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fea1:6229%em1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
br0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=9b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM>
        ether 00:50:56:a1:55:27
        inet 10.10.10.11 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.10.10.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fea1:5507%em2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
```

I want output like this:

```
em0 : 192.168.1.5
em1 : 172.16.16.16
br0: 10.10.10.11
```

`ifconfig | awk '/inet / {split($2,var,"/*"); print $1,":",var[1]}'`

`ifconfig |  grep -o "inet [0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"`

`ifconfig | sed -En -e 's/.*inet ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'`

Currently I can extract only ip addresses.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the problem that you encounter?

Comment: What have you already tried and why didn't it work. (Just listing requirements and expecting others to do it for you is off topic for Stack Overflow)

Comment: I have not problem. Just want extract all interfaces name and ip addresses. like this:
em0 : 192.168.1.5
em1 : 172.16.16.16
br0: 10.10.10.11

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Also you can extract MAC via following script:**

```
for ifcfg in $(ifconfig -lu)
do
    mac=$(ifconfig $ifcfg | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}')
    ifconfig $ifcfg | grep -v inet6 | awk -v ifcfg=$ifcfg,$mac '/inet6?/{print ifcfg mac "," $2}' | grep -v lo
done
```

**Output:**

```
em0,00:50:56:a5:42:13,192.168.1.5
em1,00:50:56:a1:62:19,172.16.16.16
```

Comment: you don't really need that complex `grep` to get the MAC address, you could simplify it with something like `ifconfig <interface> ether | awk '/ether /{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the smartest solution but you can try it :

```
while read line
do
  [[ "$line" =~ ^[a-z]+[0-9]: ]] && {
     var=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f1)
     ip=$(grep -A3 "$var" <(ifconfig)  | grep -oP 'inet.{0,15}' | cut -d' ' -f2)
     echo "$var" "$ip"
  }
done < <(ifconfig)
```

Comment: grep: The -P option is not supported

Comment: Little bit corrected but still result not excepted:
`while read line
do
  [[ "$line" =~ ^[a-z]+[0-9]: ]] && {
     var=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f1)
     ip=$(grep -A3 "$var" <(ifconfig)  | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" )
     echo "$var" "$ip"
  }
done < <(ifconfig)`

Comment: @Fuad give it a try with `egrep -o 'inet.{0,15}'`

Comment: grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"

Comment: @Fuad If you aren't matching strict IP addresses, because you'd only expect IPs, and you don't want to use egrep as suggested by funkyjelly, then you may as well just use   grep -o "inet [0-9\.]*"

Answer (score 1):

In case you have only [`csh`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?csh(1)) (default [FreeBSD shell](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/shells.html)) and need to get the IP's of interfaces `-l` that are up `-u`, you could try this:

```
$ foreach i (`ifconfig -lu`)
ifconfig $i | awk -v i=$i '/inet6?/{print i ": " $2}'
end
```

This will return IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in the format:

```
<interface>: IP
```

From the [ifconfig man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ifconfig&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html):

> The `-l` flag may be  used to list all available interfaces on the system,
>
> Option `-u` limits this to interfaces that are up.

If you just need IPv4 (`inet`) you could use something like:

```
$ foreach i (`ifconfig -lu`)
ifconfig $i inet | awk -v i=$i '/inet6?/{print i ": " $2}'
end
```

Comment: Note that `up` does not mean `status: active`: an interface can be `up` without the connection being `active`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for ifcfg in $(ifconfig -lu)
do
   ifconfig $ifcfg | grep -v inet6 | awk -v ifcfg=$ifcfg '/inet6?/{print ifcfg " : " $2}'
done
```

Hope it helps.